# Imploding a regex array into a single string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am doing something of a Twitter tags finder function in PHP and I have decided to store all the tags in a single string separated by empty space.

Currently, I am sanitizing the following string:

```
#Hello my name is #Jeanie! #PleasureToMeetYou!!!
```

And the output should be:

```
#Hello #Jeanie #PleasureToMeetYou
```

And this is my code:

```
function sanitizeTags($input)
{  
    if(preg_match_all("/#[^\s\p{P}]+/", $input, $arr))
    {
        $output = implode(" ",$arr);
        return $output;
    }
}
```

It returns me `Array` as the output. Which means that something went wrong with the implosion.

Is there a quick and easy way to store all the values of the array in a single string?

Comment: I do not see anything in this question which I would describe as a regex array. What am I missing?

Comment: Just use 0 index of regexp output array $output = implode(" ",$arr[0]);

Comment: Just a thought - in my twitter analytics I just ignore # because sometimes people tweet without tagging and the words carry the same meaning...

Comment: @dagelf So essentially all words are considered 'tag words'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sanitizeTags($input)
{  
    if(preg_match_all("/#[^\s\p{P}]+/", $input, $arr))
    {
        return implode(" ",$arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PeliCan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11612824/pelican), in the comments, [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592786/imploding-a-regex-array-into-a-single-string/56592837#comment99762479_56592786):

> Just use 0 index of regexp output array $output = implode("
>   ",$arr[0]);

which worked for me.

Comment: It is an answer - answers in comments can't be accepted, and comments are not permanent, so copying am answer from comments to an answer (with attribution) is fine.